# concurrent ml how import library

Tags: concurrency, smlnj, ml

I have downloaded Standard ML of New Jersey (SML/NJ) and now I have to use the library of concurrent Ml (CML). How can I import (use) the library?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to use a CM file (e.g., `sources.cm`) something like this:

```
Group is
    $cml/cml-lib.cm
    $/basis.cm
    your-file.sml
    ...
```

Then `sml sources.cm` should load CML correctly and make it available for use in your program.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to play around inside of SML/NJ at the prompt, you can do the following to make the CML structure available:

```
- CM.make "$cml/cml.cm";
[library $cml/cml.cm is stable]
[library $cml/cml-internal.cm is stable]
[library $cml/core-cml.cm is stable]
[New bindings added.]
val it = true : bool
-
```